# Does Quasar support Git-based blogging

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Hi does Quasar supports Git Based Blogging (i.e., read the markdown static files and render the blog)? If yes, how to achieve that?

Comment: Quasar is a framework for frontend UI components based themselves on Vue. Communication with the backend / cloud, any functionality at all you have to code yourself.

Comment: you mean this https://quasarframework.github.io/quasar-ui-qmarkdown/docs for old quasar. For new quasar https://qmarkdown.netlify.app/examples/containers.